# libmng.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I am to trying to run 64 bit version of software called `icmbrowser` (molsoft.com). I installed it but when I try to run it I get an error message:

```
./icmbrowserpro64: error while loading shared libraries: libmng.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

so tried `locate libmng.so.1` but I couldn't find it

I tried to run 32 bit version and got:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libXmu.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

so I tried `locate libXmu.so.6` and it's there

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmu.so.6 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmu.so.6.2.0
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error and why I can't run the software.

I can run run windows version on wine but it's really slow.

OS info:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

icmbrowser can be downloaded from [Molsoft](http://www.molsoft.com/download.html)

I installed it using [this procedure](http://www.molsoft.com/install-browser-linux.html)

I already tried the solution suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453452/how-to-solve-missing-libmng-so-1-in-trusty-14-04-package-is-no-more-available).It didn't help becuase the step `wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/libmng/lm‌​010010.zip` doesn't work (the file is moved permanently).

Comment: Searching using error message brought this question at top on Google

Comment: Already went through that link. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Edit the question telling what didn't work on that solution. Otherwise it'll be closed as duplicate.

Comment: This step `wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/libmng/lm010010.zip` doesn't work becuase the file is moved permananetly.

Comment: libmng1 is very old package and is removed from new distribution. found in precise repo http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libmng1&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all

Comment: I know that but the problem is why 32 bit isn't working?

Comment: I can download that File by just pointing my browser to http://ncu.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libmng/libmng-devel/1.0.10/lm010010.zip

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind `# MANUAL: add /usr/local/lib to your search path: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67781/use-shared-libraries-in-usr-local-lib` part of that solution... Again why doesn't 32 bit work even though it has everything needed?

Comment: 32bit doesn't have everything needed as it said already. The libraries you found was for 64bits. Again, you don't need to understand every bit of a solution for an installation procedure.  To install the package that provides 32bits, use `sudo apt install libxmu6:i386`